# Problemas com o selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho uma tabela e nesta tabela tenho a opção de editar.

Ao clicar na opção de editar, é aberto o *dialog* e todos os campos (colunas) da linha atual que quero editar são preenchidos.

É carregado uma lista no `selectOnMenu` mas ela não me traz o item da linha atual que escolhi para editar.

```html
<p:dialog id="dl-editar" widgetVar="editar" header="Editar Medicamento"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
    resizable="false" maximizable="false" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">

        <p:spacer height="10px;"/>
        <h:form id="form-editar">
        <p:focus/>
            <h:panelGrid id="panel-editar" columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel value="Medicamento"/>
                <p:inputText   value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.nome}" size="32" maxlength="80" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Concentracao"/>
                <p:inputText   value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.concentracao}" size="10" maxlength="80"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Preco" />
                <p:inputText   value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.preco}" size="10"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade"/>
                <p:inputText   value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.quantidade}" size="10"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Laboratorio"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.laboratorio.id}" filter="true">
                    <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{BeanMedicamento.listaLaboratorio}"  var="lista"
                        itemLabel="#{lista.sigla}" itemValue="#{lista.id}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:spacer width="35px;"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Sim" icon="ui-icon-check" 
                actionListener="#{BeanMedicamento.editar}"
                oncomplete="PF('editar').hide(); tbmedicamento.clearFilters()"
                update=":form-tabela:tabela :mensagem"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Não" icon="ui-icon-close"
                oncomplete="PF('editar').hide(); tbmedicamento.clearFilters()"
                update=":form-tabela:tabela"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        <p:spacer height="10px;"/>  
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Oiu8OXTT1eI0tTgEzTDK]

Primefaces 4.0

Javax.faces 2.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Sem analisar os detalhes da aplicação, não consigo dizer o motivo pelo qual o item não é selecionado.

Porém, sugiro que ao invés de selecionar pelo ID de um objeto (que pode estar nulo), crie um `Converter` para o componente `selectOneMenu`, conforme [exemplo da documentação](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml). Tem mais um exemplo [aqui](http://jdevelopment.nl/automatic-toobject-conversion-jsf-selectonemenu/).

Isso vai permitir que você selecione diretamente o laboratório, por exemplo:

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{BeanMedicamento.medicamento.laboratorio}" 
        converter="laboratorioConverter" filter="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{BeanMedicamento.listaLaboratorio}" var="lista"
                    itemLabel="#{lista.sigla}" itemValue="#{lista}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Para ter um item vazio, adicione um Laboratorio sem descrição ou id no início da lista e trate isso no seu `Converter`.